# where is duplication menu in object property 2.90.1?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm taking Blender classes.
The blender version of the course is 2.79.
They replicate over there like the one above, but the 2.90 version doesn't have a duplicate menu.

Comment: It's now called "instancing", in the object property panel. But several things have changed since 2.8 (no dupli group and no dupliframe now).

Comment: aha thank you so much